# If: Expression syntax - Error with a C Shell Script

Tags: unix, if-statement, expression, csh

I'm working on debugging a C-shell script that was given to me to add options to. This script, *clean,* is supposed to display the name of each file in a given directory and allows the user to decide whether or not keep or delete them. The problem is, when executed with a directory as an argument (or without) the error "If: Expression Syntax." Here's what it looks like. (now, as of 11/11)

```
## script name: clean
## helps to remove unwanted files from a directory

#!/bin/csh -vx

if ($#argv !=1) then
    echo usage: $0 directory; exit(1)
else if (! -d $1) then
    echo $1 not a directory; exit(1)
endif

set dir = $1
chdir $dir
set files = *

# process files
foreach file ($files)
    if (! -f $file) continue
    echo ' ' ## gives a blank line
    echo "file = $file" ## identifies file being processed
    echo ' '
    head $file
    while (1)
        echo -n rm $file '?? (y, n, \!, or q)' :
        set c = $<
        switch ($c)
            case y:
                if ( {rm $file} ) then
                    echo '*****' $file rm-ed
                else
                    echo cannot rm $file
                endif
                    break ## break out of while
            case n:
                echo '*****' $file not rm-ed
                break
            case q:
                exit(0)
            case \!:
                echo command:
                eval $<
                ## in $< the variable $file can be used
            endsw
        end ## of while
    end ## of foreach
```

Comment: Did you mean to close a single quote (`'`) with a double quote (`"`) after `case n:`?

Comment: Are you sure the script is even necessary? `rm -i *` does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Jonny, somehow I missed that even after parsing it a couple of times! Also Keith, yeah unfortunately this is a really roundabout way of just doing rm -i *, and is just meant to be a Unix scripting exercise as part of a class on Unix I'm taking. I didn't write the script either, and was just supposed to add more functionality to it, but it was hard to do that with a ~syntax~ error. :)

Comment: as with most (all?) shells, you can add `-vx` after your "she-bang" line at the top, you do have `#!/path2/csh` there, don't you? So, `#!/bin/csh -vx` will display lines as code (with `$var`s unexpanded), followed by line with substitutions in it, is `"var_value"`). Regardless of syntax errors, you need the "she-bang" line at the top (just reading  your last paragraph, and thats a little confusing). What do  you get for `which csh`? Good luck.

Comment: Hi shellter, `which csh` gives me `/bin/csh`. I took the shebang I mentioned out in my last paragraph of the original post above, and put in `#!/bin/csh -vx` only to get a syntax error `/home/matt/bin/clean: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token 1'`. The script's location is in a directory called bin, a child of my home directory. I'll add the updated code with the shebang above. I reckon I need more than one shebang? I apologize, I'm not the most familiar with the way `PATHS` work.

Comment: csh and tcsh scripts should have `-f` on the `#!` line. That tells the shell not to source the user's startup file(s) before executing the script. It makes it run faster and it avoids dependencies on your own environment. (This doesn't apply to sh, bash, ksh scripts; it means something completely different for them.)

Comment: Not clear about this. The "shebang" line has to be the first line in your script. Maybe that will help. Also, I recommend adding `-f` to shebang as KT mentions. After getting these resolved, let us know what the new error message is. If I have time, I'll try running this in my environment. Re PATH: The shell starts with first dir in PATH (PATH="/full/path/dir1:/full/path/dir2:...`) and searches for the first word on the command line in each of those dirs, until it finds a match, then it executes the first found based on the search order of the PATH. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks shellter, I actually got it to work yesterday, just rewrote the darn thing and added a plain `#!/bin/csh` flag and ran by it commanding it to run with `csh -f` along with full path names as arguments. Unix based systems are a fickle beast are they not? lol